# GCloud AI API returns "bad request"

Tags: python, gcloud, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I'm logged in (`gcloud auth login`) but other than that, I have no details why this command wouldn't work. Code:

```
    from google.cloud import aiplatform

    job = aiplatform.PipelineJob(display_name="MY_DISPLAY_JOB", template_path=/tmp/tmpt727de81, project=project_id, pipeline_root=project_gcp_bucket)
    job.submit()
```

Error:

```
Creating PipelineJob
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1650655555.692528693","description":"Error received from peer us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":905,"grpc_message":"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})","grpc_status":14}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daaronch/code/same-project/sameproject/ops/vertex/vertex_debugger.py", line 108, in <module>
    main(auto_envvar_prefix="SAME")
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daaronch/code/same-project/sameproject/ops/vertex/vertex_debugger.py", line 99, in deploy_vertex
    job.submit()
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/pipeline_jobs.py", line 304, in submit
    self._gca_resource = self.api_client.create_pipeline_job(
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1/services/pipeline_service/client.py", line 1281, in create_pipeline_job
    response = rpc(
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpt727de81/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})
```

Comment: Hey @aronchick long time ;-) One issue (although this shouldn't result in a 503) is that you're probably not correctly authenticated. `gcloud` doesn't authenticate code written using libraries; only `gcloud` itself. To authenticate you've options. One is to create a Service Account and export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` referencing the key. Another (discouraged) is to `gcloud auth application-default login` to use your user account credentials as a pseudo Service Account. You don't need to then set the environment variable as it should be found by ADC.

Comment: You're going to need, if you haven't, to enabled the Vertex AI service in the project `gcloud services enable aiplatform.googleapis.com --project=${PROJECT}` too. Or from the console: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/aiplatform.googleapis.com` ensure you select the correct project.

Comment: Woah, hey! So iAM logged in but I think it has to do with not having pre-created a metadata store - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71975726/creating-metadata-store-for-google-cloud-ai-platform

Comment: I'll try to find some time this afternoon to repro

Comment: oh jeez - i feel terrible :( just FYI - It's showing no metadata store (https://cln.sh/XcJ9OW) and it doesn't just happen from the CLI (https://cln.sh/QQkIVI - this was uploading the JSON directly)

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to repro creating a pipeline.

> **CAVEAT** I'm entirely unfamiliar with Vertex AI and so this is the result of my just getting anything to deploy.

I used Sascha's [example](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-vertex-ai-the-easiest-way-to-run-ml-pipelines-3a41c5ed153) (Thanks Sascha!) to generate a(ny) `pipeline.json`:

`pipeline.py`:

```py
import kfp

from kfp.v2.dsl import pipeline
from kfp.v2.dsl import component

from kfp.v2 import compiler

from os import getenv
from typing import NamedTuple

bucket = getenv("BUCKET")

@component() 
def concat(a: str, b: str) -> str:
  return a + b

@component
def reverse(a: str)-> NamedTuple("outputs", [("before", str), ("after", str)]):
  return a, a[::-1]

@component(output_component_file="component.yaml")

@pipeline(
    name="my-pipeline",
    description="My ML Pipelines", 
    pipeline_root=f"gs://{bucket}")
def my_pipeline(a: str="stres", b: str="sed"):
    concat_task = concat(a, b)
    # Per the example but `reverse_task` variable is redundant
    reverse_task = reverse(concat_task.output)

compiler.Compiler().compile(
  pipeline_func=my_pipeline, 
  package_path="my-pipeline.json",
  pipeline_name="my-pipeline"
)
```

Running the above generates `component.yaml` and `my-pipeline.json`. The latter is needed for the second step which mirrors the code in your question:

`main.py`:

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from os import getenv

project = getenv("PROJECT")
bucket = getenv("BUCKET")

job = aiplatform.PipelineJob(
    display_name="My_Display_Job",
    template_path="my-pipeline.json",
    project=project,
    pipeline_root=f"gs://{bucket}",
    parameter_values={
        "a":"foo",
        "b":"bar",
    },
)
job.submit()
```

Running this yields:

```
Creating PipelineJob
PipelineJob created. Resource name: projects/[REDACTED]/locations/us-central1/pipelineJobs/my-pipeline-20220423110750
To use this PipelineJob in another session:
pipeline_job = aiplatform.PipelineJob.get('projects/[REDACTED]/locations/us-central1/pipelineJobs/my-pipeline-20220423110750')
View Pipeline Job:
https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/locations/us-central1/pipelines/runs/my-pipeline-20220423110750?project=[REDACTED]
```

I'm unsure whether there's a `gcloud` command that enumerates pipelines but I verified that it was created in the Console.

```sh
PROJECT=
BUCKET=${PROJECT}
ACCOUNT="tester"
EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

# I think Compute is needed too
for SERVICE in "compute" "aiplatform"
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

# Going big because I'm unsure what role is required
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/editor

# Required for the pipeline
gsutil mb -p ${PROJECT} gs://${BUCKET}

# Grant Compute Engine Service Account admin on BUCKET
NUM=$(\
  gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(projectNumber)")

gsutil iam ch \
  serviceAccount:${NUM}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com:admin \
  gs://${BUCKET}

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json
export PROJECT
export BUCKET

python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install kfp
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-aiplatform

# Generate `my-pipeline.json`
python3 pipeline.py

# Create the pipeline
python3 main.py
```

Comment: HMPH. is there any chance you had created a pipeline elsewhere that created a metadata store? I feel like that's the problem here :/ 

It's showing no metadata store (cln.sh/XcJ9OW) and it doesn't just happen from the CLI (cln.sh/QQkIVI - this was uploading the JSON directly)

Comment: I think not but I'm a naive user of Vertex. I can tell you that I created a GCP Project for this and so -- IIUC -- nothing should have existed beforehand. I defer to your greater familiarity with this.

Comment: Oh, i have NO idea. :( That's why i'm here.