# Creating metadata store for Google Cloud AI Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I'm trying to do a simple basic Vertex Pipeline, and when I upload the json file, I get this:

```
Failed to create pipeline job. Error: Permission 'aiplatform.metadataStores.get' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/399668206801/locations/us-central1/metadataStores/default' (or it may not exist).
```

I can't find how to create one - the docs (https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/ml-metadata/configure) say it will be created for me. What do I need to do next?

** EDIT 1 **
Tried doing the same in the UI, similar bug:

[image: UI upload error result]

** EDIT 2 **
Here's the json:

```json
{
  "pipelineSpec": {
    "components": {
      "comp-run-info-fn": {
        "executorLabel": "exec-run-info-fn",
        "inputDefinitions": {
          "parameters": {
            "run_id": {
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          }
        },
        "outputDefinitions": {
          "parameters": {
            "run_info": {
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "comp-same-step-000-4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25-fn": {
        "executorLabel": "exec-same-step-000-4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25-fn",
        "inputDefinitions": {
          "parameters": {
            "input_context_path": {
              "type": "STRING"
            },
            "metadata_url": {
              "type": "STRING"
            },
            "run_info": {
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          }
        },
        "outputDefinitions": {
          "parameters": {
            "output_context_path": {
              "type": "STRING"
            },
            "output_context_path_2": {
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "comp-same-step-001-4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b-fn": {
        "executorLabel": "exec-same-step-001-4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b-fn",
        "inputDefinitions": {
          "parameters": {
            "input_context_path": {
              "type": "STRING"
            },
            "metadata_url": {
              "type": "STRING"
            },
            "run_info": {
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          }
        },
        "outputDefinitions": {
          "parameters": {
            "output_context_path": {
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "comp-same-step-002-5cefd94e0a9c49cdb81a6c11a5c84ac9-fn": {
        "executorLabel": "exec-same-step-002-5cefd94e0a9c49cdb81a6c11a5c84ac9-fn",
        "inputDefinitions": {
          "parameters": {
            "input_context_path": {
              "type": "STRING"
            },
            "metadata_url": {
              "type": "STRING"
            },
            "run_info": {
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          }
        },
        "outputDefinitions": {
          "parameters": {
            "output_context_path": {
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "deploymentSpec": {
      "executors": {
        "exec-run-info-fn": {
          "container": {
            "args": [
              "--executor_input",
              "{{$}}",
              "--function_to_execute",
              "run_info_fn"
            ],
            "command": [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              "\nif ! [ -x \"$(command -v pip)\" ]; then\n    python3 -m ensurepip || python3 -m ensurepip --user || apt-get install python3-pip\nfi\n\nPIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 python3 -m pip install --quiet     --no-warn-script-location 'kfp' 'dill' 'kfp==1.8.12' && \"$0\" \"$@\"\n",
              "sh",
              "-ec",
              "program_path=$(mktemp -d)\nprintf \"%s\" \"$0\" > \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"\npython3 -m kfp.v2.components.executor_main                         --component_module_path                         \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"                         \"$@\"\n",
              "\nimport kfp\nfrom kfp.v2 import dsl\nfrom kfp.v2.dsl import *\nfrom typing import *\n\ndef run_info_fn(\n    run_id: str,\n) -> NamedTuple(\"RunInfoOutput\", [(\"run_info\", str),]):\n    from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode\n    from collections import namedtuple\n    import datetime\n    import base64\n    import dill\n    import kfp\n\n    client = kfp.Client(host=\"http://ml-pipeline:8888\")\n    run_info = client.get_run(run_id=run_id)\n\n    run_info_dict = {\n        \"run_id\": run_info.run.id,\n        \"name\": run_info.run.name,\n        \"created_at\": run_info.run.created_at.isoformat(),\n        \"pipeline_id\": run_info.run.pipeline_spec.pipeline_id,\n    }\n\n    # Track kubernetes resources associated wth the run.\n    for r in run_info.run.resource_references:\n        run_info_dict[f\"{r.key.type.lower()}_id\"] = r.key.id\n\n    # Base64-encoded as value is visible in kubeflow ui.\n    output = urlsafe_b64encode(dill.dumps(run_info_dict))\n\n    return namedtuple(\"RunInfoOutput\", [\"run_info\"])(str(output, encoding=\"ascii\"))\n\n"
            ],
            "image": "python:3.7"
          }
        },
        "exec-same-step-000-4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25-fn": {
          "container": {
            "args": [
              "--executor_input",
              "{{$}}",
              "--function_to_execute",
              "same_step_000_4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25_fn"
            ],
            "command": [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              "\nif ! [ -x \"$(command -v pip)\" ]; then\n    python3 -m ensurepip || python3 -m ensurepip --user || apt-get install python3-pip\nfi\n\nPIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 python3 -m pip install --quiet     --no-warn-script-location 'dill' 'requests' 'chart_studio' 'ipython' 'matplotlib' 'numpy' 'pandas' 'plotly' 'Requests' 'scipy' 'tensorflow' 'kfp==1.8.12' && \"$0\" \"$@\"\n",
              "sh",
              "-ec",
              "program_path=$(mktemp -d)\nprintf \"%s\" \"$0\" > \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"\npython3 -m kfp.v2.components.executor_main                         --component_module_path                         \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"                         \"$@\"\n",
              "\nimport kfp\nfrom kfp.v2 import dsl\nfrom kfp.v2.dsl import *\nfrom typing import *\n\ndef same_step_000_4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25_fn(\n    input_context_path: InputPath(str),\n    output_context_path: OutputPath(str),\n    run_info: str,\n    metadata_url: str,\n) -> NamedTuple(\"StepOutput\", [(\"output_context_path\", str),]):\n    from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode\n    from pathlib import Path\n    import datetime\n    import requests\n    import tempfile\n    import dill\n    import os\n    from collections import namedtuple\n\n    # run_info = \"gAR9lC4=\"\n    # metadata_url = \"\"\n\n    input_context = None\n    with Path(input_context_path.path).open(\"rb\") as reader:\n        input_context = reader.read()\n\n    # Helper function for posting metadata to mlflow.\n    def post_metadata(json):\n        if metadata_url == \"\":\n            return\n\n        try:\n            req = requests.post(metadata_url, json=json)\n            req.raise_for_status()\n        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:\n            print(f\"Error posting metadata: {err}\")\n\n    # Move to writable directory as user might want to do file IO.\n    # TODO: won't persist across steps, might need support in SDK?\n    os.chdir(tempfile.mkdtemp())\n\n    # Load information about the current experiment run:\n    run_info = dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(run_info))\n\n    # Post session context to mlflow.\n    if len(input_context) > 0:\n        input_context_str = urlsafe_b64encode(input_context)\n        post_metadata(\n            {\n                \"experiment_id\": run_info[\"experiment_id\"],\n                \"run_id\": run_info[\"run_id\"],\n                \"step_id\": \"same_step_000\",\n                \"metadata_type\": \"input\",\n                \"metadata_value\": input_context_str,\n                \"metadata_time\": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),\n            }\n        )\n\n    # User code for step, which we run in its own execution frame.\n    user_code = f\"\"\"\nimport dill\n\n# Load session context into global namespace:\nif { len(input_context) } > 0:\n    dill.load_session(\"{ input_context_path }\")\n\n{dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(\"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\"))}\n\n# Remove anything from the global namespace that cannot be serialised.\n# TODO: this will include things like pandas dataframes, needs sdk support?\n_bad_keys = []\n_all_keys = list(globals().keys())\nfor k in _all_keys:\n    try:\n        dill.dumps(globals()[k])\n    except TypeError:\n        _bad_keys.append(k)\n\nfor k in _bad_keys:\n    del globals()[k]\n\n# Save new session context to disk for the next component:\ndill.dump_session(\"{output_context_path}\")\n\"\"\"\n\n    # Runs the user code in a new execution frame. Context from the previous\n    # component in the run is loaded into the session dynamically, and we run\n    # with a single globals() namespace to simulate top-level execution.\n    exec(user_code, globals(), globals())\n\n    # Post new session context to mlflow:\n    with Path(output_context_path).open(\"rb\") as reader:\n        context = urlsafe_b64encode(reader.read())\n        post_metadata(\n            {\n                \"experiment_id\": run_info[\"experiment_id\"],\n                \"run_id\": run_info[\"run_id\"],\n                \"step_id\": \"same_step_000\",\n                \"metadata_type\": \"output\",\n                \"metadata_value\": context,\n                \"metadata_time\": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),\n            }\n        )\n\n    return namedtuple(\"StepOutput\", [\"output_context_path\"])(str(output_context_path, encoding=\"ascii\"))\n\n"
            ],
            "image": "library/python:3.9-slim-buster"
          }
        },
        "exec-same-step-001-4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b-fn": {
          "container": {
            "args": [
              "--executor_input",
              "{{$}}",
              "--function_to_execute",
              "same_step_001_4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b_fn"
            ],
            "command": [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              "\nif ! [ -x \"$(command -v pip)\" ]; then\n    python3 -m ensurepip || python3 -m ensurepip --user || apt-get install python3-pip\nfi\n\nPIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 python3 -m pip install --quiet     --no-warn-script-location 'dill' 'requests' 'chart_studio' 'ipython' 'matplotlib' 'numpy' 'pandas' 'plotly' 'Requests' 'scipy' 'tensorflow' 'kfp==1.8.12' && \"$0\" \"$@\"\n",
              "sh",
              "-ec",
              "program_path=$(mktemp -d)\nprintf \"%s\" \"$0\" > \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"\npython3 -m kfp.v2.components.executor_main                         --component_module_path                         \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"                         \"$@\"\n",
              "\nimport kfp\nfrom kfp.v2 import dsl\nfrom kfp.v2.dsl import *\nfrom typing import *\n\ndef same_step_001_4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b_fn(\n    input_context_path: InputPath(str),\n    output_context_path: OutputPath(str),\n    run_info: str = \"gAR9lC4=\",\n    metadata_url: str = \"\",\n):\n    from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode\n    from pathlib import Path\n    import datetime\n    import requests\n    import tempfile\n    import dill\n    import os\n\n    input_context = None\n    with Path(input_context_path.path).open(\"rb\") as reader:\n        input_context = reader.read()\n\n    # Helper function for posting metadata to mlflow.\n    def post_metadata(json):\n        if metadata_url == \"\":\n            return\n\n        try:\n            req = requests.post(metadata_url, json=json)\n            req.raise_for_status()\n        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:\n            print(f\"Error posting metadata: {err}\")\n\n    # Move to writable directory as user might want to do file IO.\n    # TODO: won't persist across steps, might need support in SDK?\n    os.chdir(tempfile.mkdtemp())\n\n    # Load information about the current experiment run:\n    run_info = dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(run_info))\n\n    # Post session context to mlflow.\n    if len(input_context) > 0:\n        input_context_str = urlsafe_b64encode(input_context)\n        post_metadata(\n            {\n                \"experiment_id\": run_info[\"experiment_id\"],\n                \"run_id\": run_info[\"run_id\"],\n                \"step_id\": \"same_step_001\",\n                \"metadata_type\": \"input\",\n                \"metadata_value\": input_context_str,\n                \"metadata_time\": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),\n            }\n        )\n\n    # User code for step, which we run in its own execution frame.\n    user_code = f\"\"\"\nimport dill\n\n# Load session context into global namespace:\nif { len(input_context) } > 0:\n    dill.load_session(\"{ input_context_path }\")\n\n{dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(\"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\"))}\n\n# Remove anything from the global namespace that cannot be serialised.\n# TODO: this will include things like pandas dataframes, needs sdk support?\n_bad_keys = []\n_all_keys = list(globals().keys())\nfor k in _all_keys:\n    try:\n        dill.dumps(globals()[k])\n    except TypeError:\n        _bad_keys.append(k)\n\nfor k in _bad_keys:\n    del globals()[k]\n\n# Save new session context to disk for the next component:\ndill.dump_session(\"{output_context_path}\")\n\"\"\"\n\n    # Runs the user code in a new execution frame. Context from the previous\n    # component in the run is loaded into the session dynamically, and we run\n    # with a single globals() namespace to simulate top-level execution.\n    exec(user_code, globals(), globals())\n\n    # Post new session context to mlflow:\n    with Path(output_context_path).open(\"rb\") as reader:\n        context = urlsafe_b64encode(reader.read())\n        post_metadata(\n            {\n                \"experiment_id\": run_info[\"experiment_id\"],\n                \"run_id\": run_info[\"run_id\"],\n                \"step_id\": \"same_step_001\",\n                \"metadata_type\": \"output\",\n                \"metadata_value\": context,\n                \"metadata_time\": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),\n            }\n        )\n\n"
            ],
            "image": "library/python:3.9-slim-buster"
          }
        },
        "exec-same-step-002-5cefd94e0a9c49cdb81a6c11a5c84ac9-fn": {
          "container": {
            "args": [
              "--executor_input",
              "{{$}}",
              "--function_to_execute",
              "same_step_002_5cefd94e0a9c49cdb81a6c11a5c84ac9_fn"
            ],
            "command": [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              "\nif ! [ -x \"$(command -v pip)\" ]; then\n    python3 -m ensurepip || python3 -m ensurepip --user || apt-get install python3-pip\nfi\n\nPIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 python3 -m pip install --quiet     --no-warn-script-location 'dill' 'requests' 'chart_studio' 'ipython' 'matplotlib' 'numpy' 'pandas' 'plotly' 'Requests' 'scipy' 'tensorflow' 'kfp==1.8.12' && \"$0\" \"$@\"\n",
              "sh",
              "-ec",
              "program_path=$(mktemp -d)\nprintf \"%s\" \"$0\" > \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"\npython3 -m kfp.v2.components.executor_main                         --component_module_path                         \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"                         \"$@\"\n",
              "\nimport kfp\nfrom kfp.v2 import dsl\nfrom kfp.v2.dsl import *\nfrom typing import *\n\ndef same_step_002_5cefd94e0a9c49cdb81a6c11a5c84ac9_fn(\n    input_context_path: InputPath(str),\n    output_context_path: OutputPath(str),\n    run_info: str = \"gAR9lC4=\",\n    metadata_url: str = \"\",\n):\n    from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode\n    from pathlib import Path\n    import datetime\n    import requests\n    import tempfile\n    import dill\n    import os\n\n    input_context = None\n    with Path(input_context_path.path).open(\"rb\") as reader:\n        input_context = reader.read()\n\n    # Helper function for posting metadata to mlflow.\n    def post_metadata(json):\n        if metadata_url == \"\":\n            return\n\n        try:\n            req = requests.post(metadata_url, json=json)\n            req.raise_for_status()\n        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:\n            print(f\"Error posting metadata: {err}\")\n\n    # Move to writable directory as user might want to do file IO.\n    # TODO: won't persist across steps, might need support in SDK?\n    os.chdir(tempfile.mkdtemp())\n\n    # Load information about the current experiment run:\n    run_info = dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(run_info))\n\n    # Post session context to mlflow.\n    if len(input_context) > 0:\n        input_context_str = urlsafe_b64encode(input_context)\n        post_metadata(\n            {\n                \"experiment_id\": run_info[\"experiment_id\"],\n                \"run_id\": run_info[\"run_id\"],\n                \"step_id\": \"same_step_002\",\n                \"metadata_type\": \"input\",\n                \"metadata_value\": input_context_str,\n                \"metadata_time\": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),\n            }\n        )\n\n    # User code for step, which we run in its own execution frame.\n    user_code = f\"\"\"\nimport dill\n\n# Load session context into global namespace:\nif { len(input_context) } > 0:\n    dill.load_session(\"{ input_context_path }\")\n\n{dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(\"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\"))}\n\n# Remove anything from the global namespace that cannot be serialised.\n# TODO: this will include things like pandas dataframes, needs sdk support?\n_bad_keys = []\n_all_keys = list(globals().keys())\nfor k in _all_keys:\n    try:\n        dill.dumps(globals()[k])\n    except TypeError:\n        _bad_keys.append(k)\n\nfor k in _bad_keys:\n    del globals()[k]\n\n# Save new session context to disk for the next component:\ndill.dump_session(\"{output_context_path}\")\n\"\"\"\n\n    # Runs the user code in a new execution frame. Context from the previous\n    # component in the run is loaded into the session dynamically, and we run\n    # with a single globals() namespace to simulate top-level execution.\n    exec(user_code, globals(), globals())\n\n    # Post new session context to mlflow:\n    with Path(output_context_path).open(\"rb\") as reader:\n        context = urlsafe_b64encode(reader.read())\n        post_metadata(\n            {\n                \"experiment_id\": run_info[\"experiment_id\"],\n                \"run_id\": run_info[\"run_id\"],\n                \"step_id\": \"same_step_002\",\n                \"metadata_type\": \"output\",\n                \"metadata_value\": context,\n                \"metadata_time\": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),\n            }\n        )\n\n"
            ],
            "image": "library/python:3.9-slim-buster"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "pipelineInfo": {
      "name": "root-pipeline-compilation"
    },
    "root": {
      "dag": {
        "tasks": {
          "run-info-fn": {
            "cachingOptions": {
              "enableCache": true
            },
            "componentRef": {
              "name": "comp-run-info-fn"
            },
            "inputs": {
              "parameters": {
                "run_id": {
                  "runtimeValue": {
                    "constantValue": {
                      "stringValue": "{{workflow.uid}}"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "taskInfo": {
              "name": "run-info-fn"
            }
          },
          "same-step-000-4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25-fn": {
            "cachingOptions": {
              "enableCache": true
            },
            "componentRef": {
              "name": "comp-same-step-000-4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25-fn"
            },
            "dependentTasks": [
              "run-info-fn"
            ],
            "inputs": {
              "parameters": {
                "input_context_path": {
                  "runtimeValue": {
                    "constantValue": {
                      "stringValue": ""
                    }
                  }
                },
                "metadata_url": {
                  "componentInputParameter": "metadata_url"
                },
                "run_info": {
                  "taskOutputParameter": {
                    "outputParameterKey": "run_info",
                    "producerTask": "run-info-fn"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "taskInfo": {
              "name": "same-step-000-4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25-fn"
            }
          },
          "same-step-001-4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b-fn": {
            "cachingOptions": {
              "enableCache": true
            },
            "componentRef": {
              "name": "comp-same-step-001-4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b-fn"
            },
            "dependentTasks": [
              "run-info-fn",
              "same-step-000-4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25-fn"
            ],
            "inputs": {
              "parameters": {
                "input_context_path": {
                  "taskOutputParameter": {
                    "outputParameterKey": "output_context_path",
                    "producerTask": "same-step-000-4538957a762e4c2ea30bb0f819345e25-fn"
                  }
                },
                "metadata_url": {
                  "componentInputParameter": "metadata_url"
                },
                "run_info": {
                  "taskOutputParameter": {
                    "outputParameterKey": "run_info",
                    "producerTask": "run-info-fn"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "taskInfo": {
              "name": "same-step-001-4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b-fn"
            }
          },
          "same-step-002-5cefd94e0a9c49cdb81a6c11a5c84ac9-fn": {
            "cachingOptions": {
              "enableCache": true
            },
            "componentRef": {
              "name": "comp-same-step-002-5cefd94e0a9c49cdb81a6c11a5c84ac9-fn"
            },
            "dependentTasks": [
              "run-info-fn",
              "same-step-001-4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b-fn"
            ],
            "inputs": {
              "parameters": {
                "input_context_path": {
                  "taskOutputParameter": {
                    "outputParameterKey": "output_context_path",
                    "producerTask": "same-step-001-4847e5a4edc84257aa4ff6fe8aa0159b-fn"
                  }
                },
                "metadata_url": {
                  "componentInputParameter": "metadata_url"
                },
                "run_info": {
                  "taskOutputParameter": {
                    "outputParameterKey": "run_info",
                    "producerTask": "run-info-fn"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "taskInfo": {
              "name": "same-step-002-5cefd94e0a9c49cdb81a6c11a5c84ac9-fn"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "inputDefinitions": {
        "parameters": {
          "context": {
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          "metadata_url": {
            "type": "STRING"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "schemaVersion": "2.0.0",
    "sdkVersion": "kfp-1.8.12"
  },
  "runtimeConfig": {
    "parameters": {
      "context": {
        "stringValue": ""
      },
      "metadata_url": {
        "stringValue": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the python to attempt to run:

```py
    from google.cloud import aiplatform

    job = aiplatform.PipelineJob(display_name="MY_DISPLAY_JOB", template_path=compiled_pipeline_path, project=project_id, pipeline_root=pipeline_root)
```

Comment: Can you please share your json file or your pipeline code, and the steps you followed in creating your pipeline?

Comment: Description updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you are using vertexAI Notebook to run pipeline jobs.

The service account of the Notebook (actually a Compute Engine) should have permissions ([reference A](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/configure-project); [reference B](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)):

- roles/aiplatform.user;
- roles/storage.objectViewer;
- roles/storage.objectCreator;
- roles/iam.serviceAccountUser

One way is to do it in CloudShell (!not notebook terminal), for each role

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <your_project_id> \
--member=serviceAccount:"<your_serviceaccount_email>" \
--role="roles/aiplatform.user"
```

The service account email looks like:

```
1234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

P.S., keep in mind that the `serviceAccount` looks like an email, not the Unique ID of the service account.

P.P.S., you might get the error:

> Policy members must be of the form ":"

If so, it is because `--member` requires `serviceAccount:<service_account_name>` or `user:<user_name>`, not the account name alone.

Answer (score 1):

## Service account

One reason the Error: Permission 'aiplatform.metadataStores.get' happens is because the user/service account that is executing the pipeline component does not have the permission.

The GCP samples touches on the service account but not enough. Better to clearly tell the pipeline runtime which account to use when executing the pipeline and its components, and the way to do is tell the pipeline job which account to use.

```
job.submit(
    service_account="your service account which has the permission for Vertex AI APIs"
)
```

Comment: Right - i'm still working this through, and you're correct. The biggest problem is the docs don't detail the specific permissions via CLI on what you need to add to a service principal. That's what I'm still sorting out on my own (sadly).

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a metadata store then try to run your pipeline. Please refer doc https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/ml-metadata/configure

Comment: unfortunately, this is incorrect. In your link it says "The first time you run a PipelineJob or create an experiment in the Vertex SDK, Vertex AI creates your project's MetadataStore."

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this issue, but I don't believe it's a permission issue. In my case, I am running with aiplatform.admin permission.

If you have solved it completely, I'd like to understand. One answer that may solve your problem is to check in the VertexAI console if there is an existing Metadata Store (tab on the left) for your desired region. If not, one can attempt to create it using the linked CMEK directions, but leave off the request body specifying the key. This still works to create the store, and may help understand if it is indeed a permission or existence issue.

The particular curl command is below:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
"https://REGION_HERE-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_NAME_HERE/locations/REGION_HERE/metadataStores?metadata_store_id=default"
```

EDIT:

For anyone coming across this question later from googling the error, I was able to correct the issue using the `google.auth` module and
manually passing the `Credentials` object to the `aiplatform.init` and `pipeline.run`. The specific method is `load_credentials_from_file` documented [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.html). I also passed the full (with @ suffix) name of my service acct to each pipeline step - but I don't think that was the real reason since the error surfaces in the `pipeline.run` method.

Answer (score -1):

As it says on [the Google Cloud documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/configure-project#create-metadata-store)

1. The first step will require the creation of a configure a customer-managed encryption key (and key ring) on the Cloud Key Management System, you can find instructions on [how to do that here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/creating-keys).
2. You can create your project's default metadata store using your CMEK and an HTTP POST as shown in the [documentation] [1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/configure-project#create-metadata-store).

Comment: unfortunately, this is not correct. It's something to do with the service principal permissions.

Comment: what do you mean it is not correct @aronchick ? You are asking: how do you create a default metadata store. Do you have a metadatastore? In that case, can you add permissions to the service account you are using?

Comment: Correct - it does not involve any CMEK issues. It's purely an issue of service principal permissions, which I'm not clear on what I need to do.